# How can i grep a nearer word from a file?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

How can i grep a nearer word from a file ?

E.g

```
04-02-2010  Workingday
05-02-2010  Workingday
06-02-2010  Workingday
07-02-2010  Holiday
08-02-2010  Workingday
09-02-2010  Workingday
```

I stored above data in a file 'feb2010',

By this commend i stored date in one variable date=date '+%d-%m-%Y'

if date is 06-02-2010 , i want to grep " 06-02-2010 Workingday "

and want to store the string Working day in a variable

- How can i do this ?
- Is there any other option ?

Comment: On another note, i strongly recommend ISO8601 datetime format (%Y-%m-%d), because it is easily sortable.

Comment: Crossposted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/108265/grep-a-word-from-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
daytype=`grep $date feb2010 | cut -c13-`
```

The `grep` outputs the line, then the `cut` cuts off everything before the 13th character on that line. (Another possibility is `cut -f3 -d' '`, which outputs the field after the second space.) The result is stored in the variable `daytype`.

This assumes that the date occurs only once in the file.

Comment: using awk might be better with $2. Or cut -f2 -d" "

Comment: With two spaces between the quotes, of course. Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash

grep `date '+%d-%m-%Y'` feb2010 |
while read date type; do
  echo $type
done
```

Answer (score 1):

using the bash shell

```
#!/bin/bash
mydate=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')
while read -r d day
do
    case "$d" in
        "$mydate"*) echo $day;;
    esac
done < feb2010
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type=($(grep $date feb2010))    # make an array
type=${type[1]}                 # only keep the second element
```